# Server/database errors when using sinatra app on heroku

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, heroku, sinatra

I recently made a sample sinatra app with a Postgres database and deployed it to heroku. When using it, sometimes it work and sometimes I get an 'internal server error'.

In the heroku logs, the error reads

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError - could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds.
```

Can anyone help me address my issue? The logs read:

```
2015-06-17T15:52:41.646352+00:00 app[web.1]: 38.88.254.234 - - [17/Jun/2015 15:52:41] "GET /deck_select HTTP/1.1" 500 30 5.0016
2015-06-17T15:52:46.693209+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logout" host=calm-plains-7529.herokuapp.com request_id=cfddc08d-1598-4ec9-b9b6-774c3fac8a46 fwd="38.88.254.234" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=302 bytes=549

2015-06-17T15:52:46.764409+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=calm-plains-7529.herokuapp.com request_id=e4103cd9-79ca-4184-9a2e-365eb6e0ba27 fwd="38.88.254.234" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=2283

2015-06-17T15:52:46.689805+00:00 app[web.1]: 38.88.254.234 - - [17/Jun/2015 15:52:46] "GET /logout HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0.0012

2015-06-17T15:52:46.762402+00:00 app[web.1]: 38.88.254.234 - - [17/Jun/2015 15:52:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1492 0.0012

2015-06-17T15:52:57.515297+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=calm-plains-7529.herokuapp.com request_id=b1f9e1ff-68af-4057-9d49-add74b8f0abd fwd="38.88.254.234" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5010ms status=500 bytes=326

2015-06-17T15:52:57.512712+00:00 app[web.1]: **ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError - could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.003 seconds):**
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite self-explanatory. It means the PG instance did not reply within 5 seconds.

If it's a self-hosted PG instance, make sure the PG server is accessible. Otherwise, if it's at Heroku, you may want to check with them why it is not responding in a fashionable amount of time.